# jquery pseudo element before, content with backslash inside getting from attr(data-before)

Tags: jquery, css, icon-fonts

I have a small problem. I want to change glyphicons (icon-font) using jQuery, like this:

```
var icoList = 'E251'

var icon = $('ul > li:has(ul)', $this);
icon.addClass('icon');

icon.attr('data-before', '&#x' + icoList);          // this doesn' work, -> &#xE251
icon.attr('data-before', '\' + icoList);            // this doesn' work, -> TypeError
icon.attr('data-before', '\\' + icoList);           // this doesn' work, -> \E251
icon.attr('data-before', '"\\' + icoList + '"');    // this doesn' work, -> "\E251"
```

I only get a string.

My css is like this:

```
ul li::before {
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
    content: attr(data-before);
}
```

In my HTML I tried this:

```
<nav id="Nav-Main" class="nav-main">
    <ul>
        <li data-before="&#xE251">              <!--  this works fine  -->
            <a href="#">Home</a>

            <ul class="flexy">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Referenzen</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Downloads</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

If I use the Data in my html code, then it works fine.

What did I do wrong? How I can get this icon using code?

Comment: Note that you're missing a `;` on the character reference (in the HTML, too). It should be `&#xE251;`, not just `&#xE251`. The browser may tolerate it in some situations, but it's incorrect without the `;`.

Comment: `icon.attr('data-before', '\uE251')`

Comment: Your first attempt is correct (if we add the `;`): `icon.attr('data-before', '&#x' + icoList + ";");` It's entirely likely that you need to do something to make the Glyphicons stuff re-read the attribute, though; just setting the attribute isn't likely to make anything change.

Comment: `icon.attr('data-before', '\uE251')`...  this works right, but i cant use. I need this data from a variable.

Comment: `icon.attr('data-before', '&#x' + icoList + ";");`  this also doesn't work. Then i get `&#xE251;`